# Python django custom query result in html

Tags: python, django

Just started  to learn python django framework ,i am trying to display a custom  query result in html page.

```
def index(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM polls_post")
context ={
        'all_posts':cursor.fetchall()
    }
```

In my html page

```
<ul>
        {%  for post in all_posts %}
            <li>{{ post }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But it displays the value as tuples ,so how can i get query result with table column name such as i can print the values like this way

```
<ul>
            {%  for post in all_posts %}
                <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
                <li>{{ post.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

Comment: If you just started to learn Django, what made you think the best way was to run a raw SQL query rather than use the well-documented model layer?

Comment: I need to know to this is possible thats all:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot - using cursor you need to repack data by yourself inside view and then pass the list of **objects** to the template.

Something like

```
posts = []

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM polls_post")

    for obj in cursor.fetchall():
        posts.append({"title": obj[0], "name": obj[1]})
context = {'all_posts':cursor.fetchall()}
```

However I suppose that you rather want to use Django's ORM framework. Take a look at the [Model reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/models/) then.

Comment: Is any shorthandway to do this?? without manually using the column name

Comment: @BlessanKurien, check documentation reference – https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/db/sql/ 

There is example with use of `cursor.description`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you use sql query in your view. Try to use [Django ORM and QuerySets](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/).

May be this is helps you

Django View

```
def your_view(request):
    all_posts = your_model_class_name.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("your_html.html", {'all_posts': all_posts})
```

And in you html page

```
<ul>
    {%  for post in all_posts %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ post.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I will get unresolved reference error in `polls_post`

Comment: Pole post is your class name please replace it.

Comment: So i need to use ORM layer but i don't need it

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
def your_view(request):
    all_posts = model_class_name.objects.raw("Select * from tablename");
    return render_to_response("your_html.html", {'all_posts': all_posts})
```

and in template

```
<ul>
    {%  for post in all_posts %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ post.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

raw query are helpful when we use complex queries